# remove characters from a string, cmd input

Tags: java, string, char

I have to write a program that takes input from cmd an int N followed  by N strings and a char c and returns each of the strings with char c removed, using a method String removeChar(string str, char c).

I got it done, but without the input from cmd it worked, but when i use this code i get errors in the compiler

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String s=args[0];
        char c= s.charAt(0);
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            String b=removeChar(args[i],c);
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
    public static String removeChar(String str, char c){
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            String s1= args[i].remove(c);
        }
        return s1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code, the community might then suggest a solution.

Comment: read about `nextInt()` and `next()` from `Scanner` class in Java - follwed by FOR loops.This has been asked in Stack overflow for N times.

Comment: this is my assignment and we havent got to learn these things yet.

Comment: i can use for loops but not scanner not yet

Comment: @Batoul           Do you mean "An int N followed by a String of length N, and a char c"? I am not sure if you wrote your question correctly

Comment: no i meant what i wrote i should input an int N followed by N strings and a char c in cmd

Comment: error1 : cannot find symbol in String s1=args[i].remove(c);    error2: cannot find symbol s1    error 3: cannot find symbol n in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that my understanding of your question is correct, you needed to edit your code to be something like the following (follow my comments in the code):

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n= Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Number N

        // Hold N strings into an array
        String[] s = new String[n];

        // Capture N strings from the cmd line args
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
             s[i] = args[i+1];
        }

        // Ignore everything except the first character, which is your 'c'
        char c= args[args.length-1].charAt(0);  

        // Remove c from each of the captured strings
        for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
        {

            // Display new string with removed character 'c'
            System.out.println(removeChar(s[i],c));
        }
    }
    public static String removeChar(String str, char c){
        // Replaces all occurrences of c in str
        String c_str = ""+c;
        return str.replace(c_str, "");
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
javac A.java

java A 3 "Jason is a cowboy" "Ducky" "Huck" "c"

// Results are
Jason is a owboy
Duky
Huk
```

Does this work for you? N.B. obviously this solution is not "Silly Proof" i.e. you can enter wrong number of strings (N) and it will fall apart, but based on your main question, this is probably what you wanted to do anyway

Comment: thank you but we couldnt use arrays either. thats what's making it hard

Comment: @Batoul         your question is quite vague in that case - you have to specify these things in your original question rather than saying that the answer doesn't work